# Circular bezier path not in correct path

Tags: ios, swift, pie-chart, uibezierpath

I need to draw pie chart in a view. I have drawn the background path correctly. But when I add progress layers, paths are not drawn properly.

This is the code I use to create layers and add them to the view.

I created a gist also. You can see the full code from there also.
[MultiColoredPie Gist](https://gist.github.com/MacKaSL/99908b6937e9a57e3be39403f29b931d)

```
private lazy var pathLayers: [PieLayer] = {

        guard let data = self.data else { return [] }

        var previousPercentage: CGFloat = 0
        let sorted = data.sorted(by: { (data1, data2) -> Bool in
            return data1.percentage < data2.percentage
        })

        var layers: [PieLayer] = []
        for (index, item) in sorted.enumerated() {
            previousPercentage += item.percentage
            let layer = PieLayer()
            layer.index = index
            layer.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.square
            layer.fillColor = nil
            layer.strokeColor = item.color.cgColor
            layer.strokeEnd = previousPercentage //item.percentage
            layer.percentage = previousPercentage //item.percentage
            layers.append(layer)
        }
        return layers
}()

override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.addShapes()
}

func addShapes() {
        shapeLayer.path = commonPath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

        for layer in pathLayers.reversed() {
            print("\(layer.index) - \(layer.percentage)")
            layer.lineWidth = lineWidth
            layer.path = commonPath.cgPath
            self.layer.addSublayer(layer)
        }

}
```

I create the path with this code,

```
private var commonPath: UIBezierPath {
        get {
            let x = self.frame.width/2
            let y = self.frame.height/2
            let center = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
            let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: CGFloat(x - lineWidth/2), startAngle: -90.degreesToRadians, endAngle: 270.degreesToRadians, clockwise: true)
            path.close()
            return path
        }
}
```

Does anyone know why this happens? (and seems it doesn't start from -90)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set proper `CGLineCap`. You have `CGLineCap.square`, but you need `CGLineCap.butt`

Here is more information on it: [`CGLineCap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cglinecap)

#### Change line

```
 layer.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.square
```

#### to:

```
 layer.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.butt
```

Comment: Thank you very much. :)